Uso da preposição "mas" na oração do Pai Nosso
Por que a oração do Pai Nosso tem um "mas" no final dela? Parece um pouco fora de contexto essa conjunção, no sentido que dá a ideia de que tudo o que vêm antes está errado ou é negativo e o que está após está correto (é bom).

Pai Nosso que estais no céu,
santificado seja o vosso nome,
vem a nós o vosso reino,
seja feita a vossa vontade
assim na terra como no céu.
O pão nosso de cada dia nos daí hoje,
perdoai-nos as nossas ofensas,
assim como nós perdoamos a quem nos tem ofendido,
não nos deixeis cair em tentação
mas livrai-nos do mal. Amém.

Até pensei que a frase abaixo tem o sentido de que é uma súplica pedindo para Deus não deixar que algo ruim (tentação) aconteça com quem reza, mas sim para que, em primeiro lugar, o mal (tentação) nem sequer chegue perto da pessoa: não permita que eu lute contra o mal, mas sim que eu nem tenha que enfrentá-lo; o problema é que não sei se essa minha ideia está correta.

não nos deixei cair em tentação
mas livrai-nos do mal. Amém.


Acho que seria "não nós deixeix". Essa também é a minha interpretação: primeiro, livrai-nos do mal, mas se assim for, não mos deixeis cair em tentação. Tipo, nívels de proteção na reza.

@Schilive, pode ser que seja mesmo. Eu peguei a primeira oração que pude copiar em uma busca rápida -- para não precisar escrevê-la toda. Irei conferir o correto e corrigir.

Em termos bíblicos eu acho que a ideia é se a tentação(mal) vier, não nos deixeis cair nela, mas, se possível, livrai-nos de termos sequer essas tentações(mal).

Primeiramente, 'mas' não é uma preposição, é uma conjunção (coordenada adversativa), pois conecta orações.
Segundamente, o correto é "não nos deixeis cair", como consta no sítio digital do Vaticano.
Conjunções coordenadas adversativas estabelecem oposição entre as orações conectadas por elas. Portanto "não nos deixeis cair em tentação" está oposto a "livrai-nos do mal"; é claro, isso se nota até na própria forma dos verbos de cada oração, 'deixar' está no imperativo negativo, 'livrar' no imperativo positivo. Um é um comando para negar uma ação (ou ausência de ação), o outro é um comando para realizar uma ação.
Um detalhe importante é que, assim como 'e' (conjunção aditiva) pode ter valor adversativo, amiúde 'mas' pode ter valor aditivo — são valores conotativos (figurados) das conjunções em vez de denotativos (literais).
